# Polynomials which are invariant to the cyclic permutation of variables

Tags: polynomials, groebner-basis, computational-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following problem from [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=a12DAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=groebner%20basis%20herzog&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiS4Z6a9bHxAhUOi1wKHeo5CoEQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) book. I can find the Gröbner basis of $J$ using Buchberger’s algorithm, and so I don't have any problem with the first part of this problem. But my problem is about the second part. Could you please say how it is related to the Gröbner basis?

> Let $\eta_{0}=x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}, \eta_{1}=x_{1} \varepsilon+x_{2} \varepsilon^{2}+x_{3}, \eta_{2}=x_{1} \varepsilon^{2}+$
> $x_{2} \varepsilon+x_{3} \in \mathbb{C}\left[x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\right]$, where $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{C}$ is a primitive 3-root of unity.

> (i) Compute the reduced Gröbner basis of
> $$
> J=\left(t_{1}-\eta_{0}, t_{2}-\eta_{1}, t_{3}-\eta_{2}\right) \subset \mathbb{C}\left[x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, t_{1}, t_{2}, t_{3}\right]
> $$
> with respect to an elimination order for $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$.

> (ii) Let $f \in \mathbb{C}\left[x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\right]$ be a polynomial. Show that $f$ is invariant to the cyclic permutation of variables if and only if
> $$
> f=\sum_{\mathbf{a}=\left(a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2}\right)} c_{\mathbf{a}} \eta_{0}^{a_{0}} \eta_{1}^{a_{1}} \eta_{2}^{a_{2}}
> $$
> where $a_{1}+2 a_{2} \equiv 0 \bmod 3$ for every a such that $c_{\mathbf{a}} \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part (i) you effectively express $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in terms of $\eta_0, \eta_1, \eta_2$. Namely you get $$\left[x_{1} - \frac{1}{3} t_{1} + \frac{1}{3} t_{2} \varepsilon + \frac{1}{3} t_{2} - \frac{1}{3} t_{3} \varepsilon, x_{2} - \frac{1}{3} t_{1} - \frac{1}{3} t_{2} \varepsilon + \frac{1}{3} t_{3} \varepsilon + \frac{1}{3} t_{3}, x_{3} - \frac{1}{3} t_{1} - \frac{1}{3} t_{2} - \frac{1}{3} t_{3}\right]$$ which implies $$x_1 = \tfrac{1}{3}\left(\eta_0-\eta_1\varepsilon-\eta_1+\eta_2\varepsilon\right),\quad x_2 = \tfrac{1}{3}\left(\eta_0+\eta_1\varepsilon-\eta_2\varepsilon-\eta_2\right),\quad x_3=\tfrac{1}{3}\left(\eta_0+\eta_1+\eta_2\right).$$
Hence, by substitution, a polynomial in $x_1,x_2,x_3$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $\eta_0,\eta_1,\eta_2$, say $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \sum_{\boldsymbol{a}=(a_0,a_1,a_2)} c_\boldsymbol{a} \eta_0^{a_0}\eta_1^{a_1}\eta_2^{a_2}.$$

The cyclic permutation $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto(x_2,x_3,x_1)$ maps $$\eta_0 \mapsto \eta_0,\quad \eta_1 \mapsto x_2\varepsilon + x_3\varepsilon^2 + x_1 = \eta_1\varepsilon^2,\quad \eta_2 \mapsto x_2\varepsilon^2 + x_3\varepsilon + x_1 = \eta_2\varepsilon,$$ and hence $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is mapped to $$f(x_2,x_3,x_1) = \sum_{\boldsymbol{a}=(a_0,a_1,a_2)} c_\boldsymbol{a}\eta_0^{a_0}\eta_1^{a_1}\eta_2^{a_2}\varepsilon^{2a_1+a_2}.$$

Finally, $f$ is invariant under the cyclic permutation exactly when $2a_1 + a_2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ for all $\boldsymbol{a}$. That condition is equivalent to $a_1 + 2a_2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. This can be seen by multiplying by the invertible constant $2 \pmod 3$, or by considering the cyclic permutation in the other direction.

Comment: I don’t understand why $3x_3 = \eta_{0}+\eta_{1}+\eta_{2}$?

Comment: The reduced Gröbner basis is also a generating set for $J$, so in the quotient $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3,t_1,t_2,t_3]/J$ you have $3x_3 = t_1 + t_2 + t_3 = \eta_0 + \eta_1 + \eta_2$, and this equality $3x_3 = \eta_0 + \eta_1 + \eta_2$ continues to hold in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ because $J \cap \mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3] = \{0\}$. Alternatively, if you do the direct computation, you find $\eta_0 + \eta_1 + \eta_2 = 3x_3 + (x_1+x_2)(\varepsilon^2 + \varepsilon + 1)$, and $z^2+z+1$ is the minimum polynomial of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Got it, a very nice solution. Thanks a-lot.